# biblatex, firstinits option is deprecated, use giveninits instead

Tags: biblatex

I'm working currently with `biblatex` for my PhD thesis, to have references in each chapter. This also happened to work quite well with the styles which are given there, however as soon as I switch style to the desired one in my case (`chem-rsc`, `biblatex-chem` package is installed) I get first an error telling me:

- `Package biblatex warning: 'firstinits' option is deprecated use 'giveninits' instead.`
- And then for nearly every citation or so: `Package biblatex Warning: 'name:first-last is deprecated, please use 'name:given-family'.`

When I use a native style from the `biblatex` package these warnings do not appear, the `biblatex-chem` package is up to date (13.03.16)

Even if I simply try to compile the `biblatex-chem-rsc.tex` example file from the package I get the same errors ... any suggestions how I can handle this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{csquotes,lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-rsc]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\addbibresource{biblatex-chem.bib}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This package provides a style for \pkg{biblatex} which follows the
guidelines of Royal Society of Chemistry. The citation style is numeric
and unsorted. The bibliography style follows the pattern of the layout
used in the journal \emph{Chemical Communications}. The style should be
loaded in the usual way
\begin{verbatim}
\usepackage[style=chem-rsc]{biblatex}
\end{verbatim}
The References section of this document demonstrates the format 
generated by the package using the \texttt{biblatex-chem.bib} database
of example records.

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: The 2016-03-13 version on CTAN should not produce these warnings, make sure that is really the version you use. Add `\listfiles` to your document and post the package list from the end of the document here.

Comment: Updated all packages, now it works, thanks for the help -_-
cheers :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by a package update (see comment above).